# Woocommerce function, random order id between 1-1000

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Could someone help me out if this is possible. We use a lottery plugin with Woocommerce and it uses the order id as the ticket number. But we want it to randomize the numbers (order id) so when a user buys more than one ticket it would randomize the ticket numbers...ex. Order id 1001, 1812, 1434 and so on...and we would like to be able to to choose the sequence of numbers. Ex. from 1-2000. 
(Max 4 digits)
Is it possible to write a function for this?

Have played a litte with this i found here but it doesnt really do want we are after. No prefix or suffix are needed.

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {

```
$prefix = 'UK'; //you can create a random number for prefix
$suffix = 'INV'; //you can create a random number for suffix
$order_id = str_ireplace("#", "", $order_id);//remove # before from order id
$digits = rand(0, 1000);

$new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $digits;
return $new_order_id;
```

}

Comment: Are you planning on only ever playing one round? Shouldn't you be using a digital good and instead attach the ticket number as a custom field on the order or said good? So when a user buys multiple tickets, they buy 2 tickets on a single order/transaction. And you won't run into conflicting order numbers in your second round if you're planning on one.

Comment: You can not just use random values to begin with, then a new order could get an order id assigned, that was already taken … I think it would be a very bad idea to manipulate the order ids to begin, especially since you only seem to “need” it for your  lottery plugin. Find a better way to do your lottery, rather than messing with something to fundamental and core to the system …

Comment: Ok, if we would use a random SKU instead...would that work better? Is it possible to write a function that randomly generates a new SKU number for each buy?